# Formatting a line chart

Tags: charts, reporting, report, reportviewer, rdlc

I have a line chart in a report (rdlc), that I cannot get formatted correctly.  There are 2 main things I am trying to accomplish.

1) The x-axis is a date, right now it is being displayed as the full date with time, and I want it to be displayed as mm/dd/yyyy.  I have attempted to change this by using `=FormateDateTime(Fields!EndDate.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate)` This is exactly how I saw it in Microsoft's examples, even the one included in VS2008 (what I am using), but for some reason it says that .ShortDate is and unrecognized identifier.  I am thinking this might be a bug.  So any ideas on how to get it into the mm/dd/yyyy format?

2) I want the values that are being plotted not to be there actual value but the previous values before added to the value.  This is to accomplish a continual upward slope, showing the totals.  I would also like to filter out zero's since the first 20 entries are so are 0.  When I try to use the filter option it for some reason makes the chart just a flat line.

Any suggestions to any of these problems or a link to a good tutorial would be great as I am new to using these reports.  Thanks!

Update: I have accomplished these by applying changes to the actual data being supplied, I would still like to know an easier better way to do this.

Comment: Note: I figured out how to filter out the zeros.  I had to set the filter to != 0.  The filters are apparently backwards to what I though, in that if it is what is specified by the filter it it passed through and not filtered out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format the date in the lable under the general tab like this.
=Format(Fields!POWDate.Value, "M/dd/yyyy")

Answer (score 0):

As of now I have fixed the problem by formating the data in the SQL query to the way I would like it to be displayed in the report.